# Ignorance of already inferred type parameters for generics

Tags: c#, generics, types

Simple code like this:

```
public TRes MyMethod<TIn, TRes>(TIn data)
{
//some logic
}
```

when it called in that way:

```
var result = MyMethod("test");
```

will warn with something like "*type arguments can not be inferred from the usage, try to specify them explicitly*". While I see nothing bad in specifying `TRes`, why not compiler deduce `TIn` as it usually done?
If we say that generics signature must be remain unchanged and we can't write this

```
var result = MyMethod<int>("test");
```

then why not to omit `TIn`

```
var result = <_,int>MyMethod("test");
```

so `TRes` will be specified explicitly while `TIn` will be deduced.

Can I do something like this?

Comment: You can´t define only **some** generic arguments. You have to determine **all** at once. Anyway I can´t imagine what you actually want to **achiev**. What would be the benefit of having an object of unspecified type back? In other words: of which type should `result` be? If you won´t know its type, there´s not much you can do with it, do you?

Comment: `So the main question is how to write this all in correct way?` You know the answer - you need to be _fully_ explicit (not half explicit).

Comment: Why did they do it this way? Likely because it was simpler. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/

Comment: also you can overload it `public TRes MyMethod<TRes>(object data) => MyMethod<object, TRes>(data);`

Answer (score 0):

You can´t indicate only a *few* generic parameters while omitting others, you always have to specify either none at all and rely on the compiler to infer them for you (if this is even possible), or all at once.

If you just want to omit the result returned from your method, you can either define some arbitrary generic argument, such as `object`:

```
MyMethod<object>("Hello World");
```

or create an overload that simply calls the other overload and omits its result:

```
void MyMethod<T>(T t)
{
    MyMethod<object, T>(t);
}
```

This allows the following usages:

```
MyMethod<int>(3);
MyMethod(3);
var s = MyMethod<MyClass, int>(3);
```